# How to give developers working remotely access to Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server

I am pretty new to Azure, I need to give developers access to our database in Azure. The problem is that each time when they connect to the database, they need to whitelist client IP in the firewall which is practically frustrating.

Can someone help me find the best solution so that they don't need to do this every single time since everyone is using broadband connections they don't have a static IP so it's like practically creating new rules every single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only possible (as far as I know) with a P2S Vpn connection to a Azure VM, where the Azure VM Vnet has a private endpoint connection to the database server.

See also : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/connect-to-azure-sql-database-with-point-to-site-connection-and/m-p/1362840

Comment: I have successfully created a P2S Vpn connection and added the virtual network under firewall and virtual network of my sqlserver in Azure.I configured windows VPN client in my local machine and was able to establish connection to Azure, but when I open SQL management studio and connect my database it still ask for login to azure and whitelist my public IP. I don't know where I have done mistake.